# How to call PHP functions from a JavaScript function to access a database

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

How do you call a PHP function that is in a different file from a JavaScript function?

I have a JavaScript function that recieves a variable from an onclick function. The variable is an id that I will use to retrieve data from a MySQL database. The variable is then passed on to a PHP function that will access the database to get the data and return back to my JavaScript function for display, but it does not seem to be working. How can I get it to work? I am using [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) PHP.

Here is the code.

The JavaScript code is in a different file called `divUpdate.php`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDiv(venueID){
        //retrieveData(venueID) is a PHP function from venue_model.php
        var dest = retrieveData(venueID);
        document.getElementById('venue_description').innerHTML=dest;
    }
</script>
```

---Where the onclick function calls the JavaScript code above. ----

```
<li><a href="#self" class="menulink" class=&{ns4class};
                    onClick="changeDiv(\''.
                    $venue_details->VenueID.
                   '\')">;
```

--- Function retrieveData is called from the JavaScript code above. This is in the model (CodeIgniter). --

```
function retrieveData($venueID){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM venue WHERE VenueID = '$venueID' ");
    echo $query;
}
```

Comment: search for "ajax tutorial with php"

Comment: When you said that it doesn't work, what is actually not working?

Comment: I hope you escape $venueID somewhere.

Comment: Some google search results on stackoverflow: http://bit.ly/dh8Uxj

Comment: In the divUpdater.php the call to the method retrieveData($venueID) doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Use Ajax as already suggested. Using jQuery you will get this fixed with ease.

You will need to create a controller to access your Ajax calls.
I, simply enough, created the Ajax controller like this:

```
<?php
    class Ajax extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $this->output->set_output("This is the AJAX Controller");
        }

        public function get_venue_description( $venueId )
        {
            $this->load->model('yourmodel');
            $data = $this->yourmodel->retrieveData($venueId);
            $this->output->set_output($data);
        }
    }
?>
```

Then your JavaScript code, after implementing jQuery, should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDiv(venueID)
    {
        $.get('/ajax/get_venue_description/' + venueId, function(data) {
            $('#venue_description').html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I haven't tested it, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "AJAX" - try searching for a tutorial on google. Also, you'll find it a lot easier to perform AJAX requests by using a JavaScript library like jQuery.

Here's jQuery AJAX function:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/