# call php function that is in a different file from a javascript function to retrieve data from database

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

How do you call a PHP function that is in a different file from a JavaScript function?

I have a JavaScript function that recieves a variable from an onClick function. The variable is an id that I will use to retrieve data from MySQL database. The variable is then passed on to a PHP function that will access the database to get the data and return back to my JS function for display, but it does not seem to be working. How can I get it to work? I am using CodeIgniter PHP.

Here is my code:

JavaScript in a different file called `divUpdate.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    base_url = '<?= base_url();?>index.php/';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDiv(venueID){
        //document.getElementById('venue_description').innerHTML=venueID;
        $.get(base_url+'home/get_venue_description/' + venueID,
            function(data) {
                $('venue_description').html(data);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Where the onClick function calls the JavaScript above:

```
<li><a href="#self" class="menulink" class=&{ns4class};
  onClick="changeDiv(\''. $venue_details->VenueID . '\')">;
```

Function below is called from JavaScript above in `divUpdate.php`. The function below is also in in the model- `venue_model.php`

```
function retrieveData($venueID){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM venue WHERE VenueID = '$venueID' ");
    return $query;
}
```

Then, in the controller `home.php` I have a function that the JavaScript uses to pass the id that will then be used by the model to retrieve the data from the database

```
function get_venue_description($venueID){
    echo $this->venue_model->retrieveData($venueID);
}
```

For some reason the code in the JavaScript `divUpdater.php` doesn't work. It looks correct but doesn't work.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of another question asked by this same user, with more details added to the body of the question. Original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048282/how-to-call-php-functions-from-a-javascript-function-to-access-a-database

Comment: Agreed, this is a duplicate - the question has been answered.

Comment: Ok its a duplicate. Srrrry.!!! Can u pls help out with the question

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in your Javascript, you should do

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/foo.php?venueID=123
```

or a form in your framework, like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/action/123
```

You can use Firebug in Firefox to do a `console.log(base_url)` because it looks like

```
    base_url = '<?= base_url();?>index.php/';
    $.get(base_url+'home/get_venue_description/' + venueID,
```

and your URL is something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php/home/get_venue_description/123
```

and in your PHP file, do a

```
$venueID = $_GET['venueID'];
if (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $venueID) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM venue WHERE VenueID = '$venueID' ");
}
```

The `preg_match()` is to say, if the `$venueID` is only full of digits and nothing else.  This is to prevent SQL injection where somebody sends in some string to get your query to do something not intended by you.

Also, do some `print_r()` or `var_dump()` in your PHP file so that you can make sure what you are getting from the browser is correct.

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working. The thing is that the onclick function passes the venueID to the javascript  function changeDiv(venueID) which  passes to $.get(base_url+'home/get_venue_description/' + venueID, which retrieves from the database but the thing is that it doesnt seem to be working. Ur solution doesnt seem to wor. where are u getting $venueID = $_GET['venueID']; from in ur code